# mysql query with in array and one more condition

Tags: mysql, arrays

I have a mysql query as follows

```
"SELECT * FROM `listings`
WHERE `category` IN (".implode(",",$search_category_list).")
OR `title` LIKE '%".$search_for."%'
ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 10"
```

It gives result for first condition only. I'm not getting result from second condition.  But if I remove the first condition and run the query, i.e

```
"SELECT * FROM `listings`
WHERE `title` LIKE '%".$search_for."%'
ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 10"
```

it works fine.

Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: You are using `OR`, so if it matches the `IN` it won't check the `LIKE`.  Did you mean to use `AND` instead of `OR`?

Comment: no!... i need to check with OR only both conditions are for diff column

Comment: is $search_category_list array of string or numbers?

Comment: $search_category_list is array of numbers

Comment: @user3680502: `OR` will return rows where *either* of those conditions is true.  So, it will first check the `IN` and it will *only* check the `LIKE` if the `IN` is false.  Maybe you just need to increase the `LIMIT` to show you more results?

Comment: @Rocket Hazmat you r rite. but i have some rows those have IN is false and LIKE is true, but in result that rows didnt come. tht is the problem im asking here..  iam checking wit only 15 rows table.

Comment: Is there anybody to solve this issue?